# How to Add User's First Name and Last Name in Social Media Profile to Claims in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 and added Twitter Authentication to the Authentication Pipeline.

It authenticates the user successfully which is fine. But I need it to add the user's First Name and LastName as Claims in my `profileService` (`JwtClaimsTypes.GivenName` and `JwtClaimsTypes.FamilyName`) to use it in my application but it only returns `preferred_username`, `name`, `emailaddress` etc. Please I need help on this. Below is my IdentityProfileService.cs

```
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
        if (sub != null)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            var cp = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

            var claims = cp.Claims.ToList();

            claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

            //claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes., $"{ user.LastName}, {user.FirstName}"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.LastName));
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
                claims.Add(new Claim("full_name", $"{ user.LastName}, {user.FirstName}"));
            }
            else
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, ""));
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, ""));
                claims.Add(new Claim("full_name", ""));
            }

            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var userRole = roles.FirstOrDefault();
            if (userRole != null)
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            else
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "General"));
            context.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the claims are added, but not mapped in the client. Are you familiar with this article: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/ As a side note: I don't think you'll need to override the profile service to add this information. You should be able to configure this in IS4.

Comment: Does Twitter provide other scopes for you to access this information?

Comment: @Brad Actually, our thoughts are similar. How can I access Twitter scopes to get as much information from the user profile like profile picture and the user's display name/ full name. The only claims I get from the `ExternalLoginInfo` are the user handle and the user ID.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yea I'm familiar with that article. It actually helped me to add more claims that are not part of the default claim collection. I had that issue a couple of weeks ago. But see my previous comment for a more specific issue

Comment: Have you debugged the code and used a breakpoint here to see what is available in the context?

Comment: @aaronR I don't know what context you're talking about. But I debugged to find out the claims it returns from the `ExternalLoginInfo`

Comment: Context - the variable name that is passed into the function.

Comment: I see the claims are coming from the _claimsFactory which is not the twitter claims. You have to check your code in the claimsFactory to see what claims you are adding.

Comment: @aaronR the `_claimsFactory` is of type `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>` which is injected in the profile service class. amongst other claims it returns, this is the only one I get from the `ExternalLogin` `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`, `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`, `urn:twitter:userid`, `urn:twitter:screenname`. The screenname returns the twitter handle actually. But I also need the display name and profile picture of the signed in user. I hope you get my point.